# Visual Studio Not reporting Any Useful Error Message on Terminal when Building Official Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I build microsoft official project through VS code, I found it always report "The "CompileXaml" task returned false but did not log an error." instead of any specific error message indiciating the line number whenever a simple error happens. I hope the terminal provide a slightly more useful message. Do you know how I can achieve that? It report accurate error message when I run other programs.

The sample is the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothle/

It always report the following if I type any line wrong in the file Scenario1_Discovery.cs
[image: Error Message]

By the way, it seems that same problem occur on other Microsoft Sample project such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/deviceenumerationandpairing/
Basically, any error occurred at the project will not be shown in any detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by closing all VS instances and deleting the hidden .vs, bin and obj folders in the project folder.